# Return IDs list of nested normalized data in result

Tags: javascript, json, normalization, normalize, normalizr

For example I have a simple JSON, like this:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "325",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Alex"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And after normalizing with [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) and schemas from [example](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr#quick-start)

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

// Define a users schema
const user = new schema.Entity('users');

// Define your comments schema
const comment = new schema.Entity('comments', {
  commenter: user
});

// Define your article 
const article = new schema.Entity('articles', { 
  author: user,
  comments: [ comment ]
});

const normalizedData = normalize(originalData, article);
```

I will get this normalized JSON:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324", "325" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" },
      "3": { "id": "3", "name": "Alex" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" },
      "325": { id: "325", "commenter": "3" }
    }
  }
}
```

In `normalizedData.result`, I will get only articles IDs. But what if I need IDs of `comments` or `users`. Basically I can get it with `Object.keys()`, may be is there any other way, normalizr can provide us from API to get this data at step of normalization? I can't find anything about it it [API](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md). Or can you suggest any methods to do it, not automatically? Because `Object.keys()` not looks good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value you're normalizing is an `article`, the `result` value from Normalizr will be the Article's ID. As you suggested yourself, if you need to the IDs of a different, nested entity type, you'll have to use something like `Object.keys(normalizedData.entities.comments)`